# Code that compiles with ghc but not with cabal new-run

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have this program `Main.hs`:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    if False then undefined 
    else do
    let x = 5
    print x
```

When I compile it with `ghc Main.hs` it compils well generating a `Main` executable, but when (after initializing cabal with `cabal init`) I try to make a `cabal new-run` it gives an error:

```
$ cabal new-run
Build profile: -w ghc-8.6.5 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - ghc-vs-cabal-0.1.0.0 (exe:ghc-vs-cabal) (file Main.hs changed)
Preprocessing executable 'ghc-vs-cabal' for ghc-vs-cabal-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'ghc-vs-cabal' for ghc-vs-cabal-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, /home/ivan/ghc_vs_cabal/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.5/ghc-vs-cabal-0.1.0.0/x/ghc-vs-cabal/build/ghc-vs-cabal/ghc-vs-cabal-tmp/Main.o )

Main.hs:4:10: error: Empty 'do' block
  |
4 |     else do
  |          ^^
```

With `cabal run` it also gives error.

I have cabal version `2.4.0.0`:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 2.4.0.0
compiled using version 2.4.0.1 of the Cabal library
```

And ghc version `8.6.5`:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.5
```

Does somebody know what is happening?

I know that I can fix it if I add indentation:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    if False then undefined 
    else do
        let x = 5
        print x
```

But I want to know why it compiles with `ghc` but not with `cabal new-run`

Comment: Strange indeed. (I daresay GHC is just wrong here, this should not parse... but it certainly shouldn't be Cabal to judge this...)

Comment: Relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/m3fus1/have_do_block_indentation_rules_changed/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code requires a language extension to parse: `NondecreasingIndentation`. This extension exists to avoid the awkward runaway effect of nested `do`s

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    if False then undefined 
    else do -- next block should be indented in standard Haskell
        let x = 5
        print x -- ...but this can easily get out of hand if you do it multiple times
```

`NondecreasingIndentation` allows a nested `do` block to register as nested as long as it's indented *as much as* the containing block, instead of *more than* the container.

According to the [GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/bugs.html#context-free-syntax), `NondecreasingIndentation` is on by default but disabled in `Haskell2010` mode (unless explicitly enabled again). I can't find the corresponding `cabal` documentation, but we can probably guess it defaults to specifying `Haskell2010`.

You can specify extensions in a source file to be enabled or disabled regardless of external options by adding a pragma like

```
{-# LANGUAGE NondecreasingIndentation #-}
```

to the very top of the file.